# localStorage removeItem not working for Key-value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

any idea why my code doesn't remove the key-value pair from localStorage?
If I console log rowItem it is precisely as written in localStorage. If I hardcode the exact same string for example: localStorage.removeItem("Puppy") it is removed from localStorage. Any advice?

Link to app: http://kajlax.mbnet.fi/Projects/Kauppalista

```
// Remove item
$("#shoppingTable > tbody").on("click", "i", (function(){
    let currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    let rowItem = currentRow.find("td:eq(0)").text().substring(1);

    // Delete from LS
    localStorage.removeItem(rowItem);

    // Delete from UI
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
}));
```

Thank you Aamir Nakhwa for pointing out the error. It wasn't in this function but in another function in which I changed the selector:

```
$(".ui.container").on("click", "tr",(function(){
```

Both functions used a similar selector #shoppingTable and caused a collision.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked your [demo link](http://kajlax.mbnet.fi/Projects/Kauppalista/) and want to make you clear that this line is working fine

localStorage.removeItem(rowItem); **All Good**

Actually after removing item, this event fired 
$("#shoppingTable > tbody").on("click",

and it execute your **else clause** which add item again in localStorage by following line

localStorage.setItem(stateOfItem, 0);

You can confirm it by log something from your else clause